# what is the opposite of re.findall

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have some code finding the occurences of my regex

`r"ABC E?(?P<prefix>AA) (?P<number>\d+)( n\.F\.)?(, Tz. (?P<rz>\d+)( f?f\.?)?)?"`

Using `re.findall` gets a list of 170 occurences in my Text - seems to be a valid number of matches.

Now I wanted to get a list of the non matching parts in my text and so i used `re.split`

Using `re.split` brings a list with the count of 1 - so no splitting happened.

I also tried to tear down the problem

```
content = '''Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et 
    accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna 



    aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'''

regex = r"et"

print len(re.findall(regex, content, re.MULTILINE | re.UNICODE | re.DOTALL))
print len(re.split(regex, content, re.MULTILINE | re.UNICODE | re.DOTALL))
```

This brings a count of 18 and 19 which looks much better. I think I have some Problems using more complex regular expressions.

Hope you have any suggestions.

Comment: It might help your question if you include a simpler form of the pattern, or at least describe what you are trying to match in your text.

Answer (score 0):

Simple `re.split` won't work the way you want due to the fact that you have capturing groups in your regex. From the [documentation of `re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split):

> If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list.

So one solution would be to first replace the matches with some fixed character/string and then split on this:

```
s = re.sub(regex, '|', content, re.MULTILINE | re.UNICODE | re.DOTALL)
s = s.split('|')
```